# Using a window to apply aggregations on multiple columns of a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to apply aggregate functions to multiple columns in a window of a dataframe in pyspark?

For example, I know I can do something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

columns = ["id", "x","y",  "timestamp"]
values = [
    (1, 1, "test","2018-12-31"),
    (1, 3, "test","2018-11-30"),
    (1, 5, "test1","2018-09-30"),
    (1, 2, "test1","2018-08-31")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(values, columns)
df = df.withColumn("date", f.to_date("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
w = Window.partitionBy("x").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(-(3 - 1), 0)
```

Now if I want to apply aggregations on all columns:

```
agg_list = [f.avg, f.sum, f.max, f.min]
for c in df.columns[1:3]:
    for af in agg_list:
        df = df.withColumn(str(c) + '_'+ af.__name__, af(c).over(w))
```

This works fine but I would like to know if there is a better way to do this? I know that in a groupBy I can apply these aggregations in a single statement to all columns, without writing all those for loops, is there a similar approach but for Windows?

Especially for larger datasets and multiple time windows, this seems to take a long time.

Thanks!

Comment: There are syntactically multiple ways to do what you are asking, but they will likely be equivalent from an execution plan standpoint. Even though you've coded a loop, these aggregations are not actually happening one at a time.

Comment: @pault I'm aware, but for some reason this is still taking a long time for large data  (0.8M rows by 40 cols). I can't figure out why it would take so long. The only difference with the example here is that I have one more for loop at the top level for 3 different window sizes.

Comment: Show the physical plan from web UI. What action do you do on `df`? That's what takes time.

Comment: I've hosted an example of the execution plan ( https://github.com/pauldg/files/blob/master/execution_plan.txt ), before it gets too big and I get a stackoverflowerror when trying to use .explain()