# Applying many window-aggregate functions to many columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there any way to add columns from many window aggregate functions to all columns, minus a couple from a dataframe in pyspark?. The DataFrame can have a varying amount of columns that can't be known in advance

When using groupBy in Pyspark, you can do the following to add many aggregations to many different columns

```
exprs = {x: ["sum", "mean"] for x in df.columns}
df.groupBy("col1").agg(exprs).show()
```

I am looking for a way to do something similar, but with Window - Aggregate Functions
I would like to be able to do something like

```
window = Window.partitionBy(col1).orderBy(col2).rangeBetween(window, -1)

exprs = {x: ["sum", "mean"] for x in df.columns}

df.select(*, exprs.over(window))
```

To be able to do all the window aggregations for all the columns in a clean way, writing them out manually is not an option as the columns can't be known in advance of each run, and there is hundreds - thousands of them.

I see this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444259/using-a-window-to-apply-aggregations-on-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-in-pyspa), but not answer is given

Comment: I had suggested the same thing as mentioned in your linked post: use a for loop.